# Backbone pre rendering of collection models

Tags: backbone.js

I want to perform an action, clearing parent element, after a collection has fetched his models but prior to the models rendering.

I've stumbled upon [before and after render methods](https://gist.github.com/sagar-ganatra/4632091) yet they are model specific, which will cause my parent element to clear before every model rendering.

I'm able of course to perform the action pre-fetching yet I want it to occur when fetch is done and before models are rendered.

I tried using reset and change events listening on the collection yet both resulted unwanted end result.
Reset event seamed to go in that direction yet the passed argument was the entire collection and not a single model from the collection, therefore using the add event callback wasn't possible due to difference in argument type (collection and not a model as required)

Any ideas how to invoke a callback when fetch a collection fetch is successful yet models are yet to be rendered?

The model contains the returned attributes while collection contains url for fetching and parse method to return argument wrapped object.

Below is the code I use to render the collection view, which is basically rendering each model's view within the collection.

```
Collection View
---------------
var FoosView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#plans',
        events: {
            //'click tr': 'rowClick'
        },
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderNew);

            _.bindAll(this, "render");

            this.render();
        },
        renderNew: function(FooModel) {

            var item = new FooView({model: FooModel});
            this.$el.prepend(item.render().$el);
        }
        ...
    });

The model view
--------
var FooView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        initialize: function(options) {
            this.options = options || {};
            this.tpl = _.template(fooTpl);
        },
        render: function() {
            var data = this.model.toJSON();

            this.$el.html(this.tpl(data));

            return this;
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Shahar, Like Francois I'm not really sure I understand your question. I think you are asking to empty the parent list when the collection reloads/resets? You can't use the renderNew() method because the argument from the `reset` event is a list of models rather than a single model, is that correct? So you want to use `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.someNewMethod);`, where someNewMethod starts by clearing the list and then rendering the elements. Let me know if that sounds about right.

Comment: I tried working with reset yet I had problem rendering the passed argument, since it was a collection and not a single module (I tried using within the reset callback the renderNew method, I guess that was my mistake...

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the reset event is what you want. I will put up an answer for you explaining how to go about it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I understand your question and here is a proposed solution. You are now listening to the `reset` event on your collection and calling `this.renderAll`. `this.renderAll` will take the list of models from the collection and render them to the page, but only AFTER the list element has been emptied. Hope this helps :).

```
var FoosView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#plans',
    collection: yourCollection, // A reference to the collection.
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderNew);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.renderAll);
    },
    renderAll: function() {
        // Empty your list.
        this.$el.empty(); 
        var _views = []; // Create a list for you subviews
        // Create your subviews with the models in this.collection.
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            _views.push(new FooView({model: model});
        });
        // Now create a document fragment so as to not reflow the page for every subview.
        var container = document.createDocumentFragment();
        // Append your subviews to the container.
        _.each(_views, function(subview) {
            container.appendChild(subview.render().el);
        });
        // Append the container to your list.
        this.$el.append(container);
    },
    // renderNew will only run on the collections 'add' event.
    renderNew: function(FooModel) {
        var item = new FooView({model: FooModel});
        this.$el.prepend(item.render().$el);
    }
});
```

I am forced to assume a few things about you html, but I think the above code should be enough to get you up and running. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Exactly what my intentions were, I guess it's all about the way I choose to render. sorry @François Richard, I guess I wasn't clear enough :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure about what you are asking but have you tried:

```
MyCollection.fetch({
    success: function(models,response) {
         //do stuff here
    }
});
```

Also you may be interested taking a look at http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

Hope it helps!

Edit: there is no direct link between fetching and rendering my bet is that you binded rendering to model change.

**USE**===============>>>> http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did tried that but the success call is made after models have been rendered. I want to call a function after fetch has been successful yet models are yet to be rendered to the DOM. Is that optional?

Comment: you define the rendering so I can't tell what's going on without code, how did you define your rendering ?

Comment: I've updated the code I use to render the collection views, which is simply rendering each model within the collection pretty much. Let me know if anything else is required to complete the puzzle :). Thanks.
renderNew method is called for every retrieved model, therefore not optional for my reset behavior I want to perform (clearing parent element prior to models rendering.

Comment: use the .parse method

Comment: Wouldn't parse trigger after every model fetch? in case I have changing number of models returned to the collection parse would be invoked after every fetched one, no?

Comment: you change event from the collection will be trigger after the aprse, so you can work on it before your rendering